# How to use routing-controllers with swagger ui?

Tags: express, swagger-ui, routing-controllers

i don't understand, how to use swagger-ui with routing-controller.

i have tried:

```js
@Controller('/api-docs')
@UseBefore(swagger.serve) //ERROR No overload matches this call
class SwaggerController {
  
  @Get('/')
  @UseBefore(swagger.setup(swaggerJson))
  public swaggerUi(): void {}
}
```

but i got Error (No overload matches this call) for swagger.serve.

Now, i made it so:

```js
// server.ts
const app = express();

useExpressServer(app, {/* controllers, middlewares, options */});

app.use('/api-docs', swagger.serve, swagger.setup(swaggerJson));
```

it works, but this is incorrect implementation (i think)

How use existing middlewares for that cases?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the right implementation, as recommanded on [swagger-ui-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/swagger-ui-express) documentation.

As decribed in [routing-controllers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers#pre-configure-expresskoa) documentation, you can pre-configure your Express app with common Express middlwares, then setup routing-controllers using `useExpressServer(app, ...`

> No need to create any dedicated Controller, simply add it as a `function` middleware

I'm using Routing-Controller / Express typescript project, and I
configured Swagger this way (using YML openAPI file, but could be JSON
as well), **except that I configure express BEFORE routing-controllers setup:**

```js
import * as swaggerUi from "swagger-ui-express";
import * as YAML from "yaml";
...

{
    const app = express();
    ...
    // load YML Swagger spec
    const buf = await fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, "../install/openapi.yml"));
    const openApi = YAML.parse(buf.toString());
    // setup swaggerUI as Express middleware
    app.use("/api-docs", swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(openApi));

    // then setup routing-controller
    useExpressServer(app, { ...
    ...
}
```